# Select all checkbox option works only one time after page refresh in a gridview placed in jQueryUI tabs?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working in an application in which i have to show select all checkbox in header which selects all rows in a gridview and there are 2 different gridviews in a page in two different jQueryUI tabs.

My code is

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checkbox").click(function () {
                    //Get number of checkboxes in list either checked or not checked
                    var totalCheckboxes = $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checkbox").size();
                    //Get number of checked checkboxes in list
                    var checkedCheckboxes = $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checkbox:checked").size();
                    //Check / Uncheck top checkbox if all the checked boxes in list are checked
                    $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkAll']:checkbox").attr('checked', totalCheckboxes == checkedCheckboxes);
                });

                $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkAll']:checkbox").click(function () {
                    //Check/uncheck all checkboxes in list according to main checkbox 
                    $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checkbox").attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
                });
            });
</script>
</head>

<asp:GridView ID="gvOpenTickets" TabIndex="11" runat="server" Height="176px" Width="100%"
                                                BackColor="#EEEEEE" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Verdana" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                HorizontalAlign="Left" DataKeyNames="IssueCategory,Type,userid,AssignedTo,Details,Id"
                                                Font-Name="Verdana" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" ShowFooter="false" OnRowDataBound="gvOpenTickets_RowDataBound">
                                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black">
                                                </HeaderStyle>
                                                <FooterStyle BorderColor="Black" BackColor="Black"></FooterStyle>
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-Width="40px">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TicketDate") %>' ID="lblDate" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details" HeaderStyle-Width="230px">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>' ID="lblDetails" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAll" />
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkEmployee" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
```

Problem is that the select all option only works one time when I click on header row after page refresh and then it does not work.

Comment: Is your code inside update panel??

Comment: no there is no update panel

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your click event with .live as..

```
$("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checkbox").live("click", "chkEmployee", function (event) {
                    //Get number of checkboxes in list either checked or not checked
                    var totalCheckboxes = $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checkbox").size();
                    //Get number of checked checkboxes in list
                    var checkedCheckboxes = $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checkbox:checked").size();
                    //Check / Uncheck top checkbox if all the checked boxes in list are checked
                    $("#<%=gvOpenTickets.ClientID%> input[id*='chkAll']:checkbox").attr('checked', totalCheckboxes == checkedCheckboxes);
                });
```

if it doesn't work you can bind your chkemployee field on itemdatabound (which is listview event, i don't know its equivalent of gridview) dynamically as..

```
chkEmployee.Attributes.Add("onclick","return YourFunctionname('"+chkEmployee.ClientId.ToString()+"')");
```

and finally put your  code  inside this function.